# Primer for learning about quantum circuits simulating systems

Tags: circuit-construction, resource-request, chemistry, many-body-systems

I am interested in a couple of books or arXiv links to learn how to develop quantum circuits for the purpose of simulating quantum multi-body systems. Moreover, I am interested in learning how to develop an ansatz from a quantum circuit.

Any suggestions will be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What's your current level of familiarity with quantum computing and with many body quantum systems? I'll take a stab anyway and recommend https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0108146

Comment: Thank you! I am not an expert-expert but I do have physics training. If you think another paper can also be of help, please let me know!

Comment: How is the level of that paper?

Comment: I can follow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fairly thorough overview: https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.6253

For completeness I'll include the paper from the comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0108146